Convert XML table into tibble in R
I'm trying to transform XML tables with varied numbers of rows and columns into dataframes. I can do this with well-formatted, predictable tables, like these two:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <table xml:id="a">
        <row role="label">
            <cell cols="2">Stuff</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Thing</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Another thing</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
    <table xml:id="b">
        <row role="label">
            <cell cols="2">Nonsense</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Thing</cell>
            <cell>3</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Anything</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Another thing</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
</body>

I can change these into a tibble like this:
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  id    label    cell.1        cell.2
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>
1 a     Stuff    Thing              1
2 a     Stuff    Another thing      2
3 b     Nonsense Thing              3
4 b     Nonsense Anything           2
5 b     Nonsense Another thing      2

Using this code:
x <- "table.xml"
file <- read_xml(x)
cells <- file %>% xml_find_all(".//cell")
output <- lapply(cells, function(d){
  id <- d %>% 
    xml_find_first(".//parent::row/parent::table")%>% 
    xml_attr("id")
  label <- d %>% 
    xml_find_first(".//parent::row/preceding-sibling::row[@role='label']")%>% 
    xml_text()
  cell.1 <- d %>% 
    xml_find_first(".//parent::row/cell")%>% 
    xml_text() 
  cell.2 <- d %>% 
    xml_find_all(".//following-sibling::cell")%>%
    xml_double() 
  tibble(id, label, cell.1, cell.2)
})
answer <- do.call(rbind, output)

However, this approach relies on supplied attributes (@role='label'), consistent numbers of cells, etc. I need to run this script over a bunch of irregularly formatted XML tables.
My approach breaks down if I add one extra cell to one of the rows in the example above. I suspect I may be approaching this problem the wrong way. For example, could I do this with xml2::as_list()? I haven't had success in my attempts.
My real-world use case involves complicated TEI-XML documents like this one: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dig-eg-gaz/content/master/1905-07-12.xml. From these documents, I select the tables I want to extract using attributes, like this xml_find_all(".//d1:body/d1:div/d1:div[@feature='stocksShares']//d1:table").

Update 04.04 : Another way to do it regarding the data you've provided.
### Packages (you'll need to install scraEP)
library(XML)
library(xml2)
library(scraEP)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

### We remove the XML namespace from the file and parse it
rez=read_xml("C://Users/YourName/Downloads/YourFile.xml") %>% xml_ns_strip()
test=xmlParse(rez)

### We count the number of tables inside the XML
nb_tab=1:xpathSApply(test,'count(//div[@feature="stocksShares"]/table)')

### We are going to write 2 functions : one to loop over the tables and another to loop over the rows which contain (or not) a label
### First, we generate the maximum number of cells for each table with the @cols attribute
### We store the result into a named vector which will be used later for the data extraction

zoro=function(x){
  j=xpathSApply(test,paste0("(//div[@feature='stocksShares']/table)[",x,"]/@cols"))
  vecteur=setNames(paste0("./cell[",1:j,"]"),paste0("cell.",1:j))
  ### We count the number of "label" per table and manage the case when there'are none
  jj=xpathSApply(test,paste0('count((//div[@feature="stocksShares"]/table)[',x,']/row[@role="label"])'))
  ifelse(jj==0,kk<-1,kk<-jj)
  nb_lab=1:kk
  babar=function(y){
    ## We create the labels
    titre_label=paste0('(//div[@feature="stocksShares"]/table)[',x,']/row[@role="label"][',y,']//text()')
    titre_label_OK=paste0(xpathSApply(test,titre_label,xmlValue),collapse = " ")
    #### We extract the data with the apropriate XPath (if there are labels or none)
    ifelse(jj==0,rows<-paste0("(//div[@feature='stocksShares']/table)[",x,"]/row"),
           rows<-paste0("(//div[@feature='stocksShares']/table)[",x,"]/row[not(@role)][./preceding::row[@role='label'][1]=(//div[@feature='stocksShares']/table)[",x,"]/row[@role='label'][",y,"]]"))
    exit=xscrape(test,row.xpath = rows,col.xpath = vecteur,
                 page.name = FALSE,
                 parallel = 1)
    ## We add header of each table and the labels
    header=paste0('(//div[@feature="stocksShares"])[',x,']/head')
    end=exit %>% mutate(head=xpathSApply(test,header,xmlValue),
                        label=titre_label_OK,.before = 1)
  }
  titi=map(nb_lab,babar)
  ## We stack the intermediate tables
  bind_rows(titi)
}
lafin=map(nb_tab,zoro)

Output :
# A tibble: 48 × 6
   head              label         cell.1 cell.2 cell.3                                cell.4
   <chr>             <chr>         <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                                 <chr> 
 1 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "Lst." 13 ¾   Imperial Ottoman Bank                 —     
 2 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "\""   26 1/4 Nat. Bank of Egypt                    —     
 3 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "\""   —      do do New                             26 1/4
 4 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "Fcs." 426 —  National Bank of Greece               —     
 5 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "L.E." — 1/16 Banque Industrielle                   —     
 6 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "Fcs." 815 —  Credit Foncier Egyptian Lottery Bonds 317   
 7 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "Lst." 13 7/8 Agricultural Bank                     9 1/2 
 8 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "Fcs." 122 -- Banque d'Athènes                      —     
 9 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "Lst." 1 3/8  Egypt. Investment Co.                 —     
10 STOCKS AND SHARES Shares BANKS. "\""   9 5/16 Land Bank of Egypt                    90

# A tibble: 17 × 5
   head             label   cell.1                              cell.2 cell.3 
   <chr>            <chr>   <chr>                               <chr>  <chr>  
 1 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Rente Française 3 %                 "Fr."  99 17  
 2 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Actions de Suez                     "\""   4440 - 
 3 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Lots Turcs                          "\""   132 5- 
 4 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Turc Unifié                         "\""   89 20  
 5 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Dette Egyptienne Unifié             "\""   107 40 
 6 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Daïra Sanieh                        "\""   102 ---
 7 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Crédit Foncier Egyptien             "\""   840 ---
 8 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Extérieur espagnol                  "\""   90 47  
 9 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Obl. Banque Nat. de Grèce           "\""   428 -- 
10 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Banque d'Athènes, nouvelles actions "\""   124 ½  
11 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Métropolitain                       "\""   - -    
12 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Russe consolidé                     "\""   85 60  
13 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Sosnowice                           "\""   --     
14 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Change sur Londres                  "\""   25 15 ½
15 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Sucre No 3 disponible               "\""   --- ---
16 TELEGRAMME HAVAS PARIS   Sucre No 3 livrable le 4 de mars    "\""   --- ---
17 TELEGRAMME HAVAS LONDRES Consolidés anglais                  "£"    90 ¼

# A tibble: 38 × 7
   head       label cell.1                          cell.2 cell.3        cell.4 cell.5    
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>                           <chr>  <chr>         <chr>  <chr>     
 1 SHARE LIST ""    "Agric. Bank of Egypt"          "Lst." 13 7/8        "à"    9 7/16 à ½
 2 SHARE LIST ""    "Nat. Bank of Egypt"            "\""   26 5/16 à 3/8 "\""   — —       
 3 SHARE LIST ""    "Ramleh Railway"                "\""   7 1/8         "\""   — —       
 4 SHARE LIST ""    "Egyptian Delta Railway ex.-c." "\""   12 7/8        "\""   — 15/16   
 5 SHARE LIST ""    "Tram. d'Alexandrie"            "Fos." 162 —         "\""   — —       
 6 SHARE LIST ""    "\" \" div."                    "\""   340 —         "\""   — —       
 7 SHARE LIST ""    "Alexandria Water"              "Lst." 15 —          "\""   — —       
 8 SHARE LIST ""    "Eaux du Cairo"                 "Fcs." 1110 —        "\""   — —       
 9 SHARE LIST ""    "Daira Sanieh"                  "Lst." 28 1/16       "\""   — 1/8     
10 SHARE LIST ""    "Béhéra"                        "L.E." — —           "\""   — —

# A tibble: 42 × 6
   head                   label cell.1                          cell.2  cell.3 cell.4
   <chr>                  <chr> <chr>                           <chr>   <chr>  <chr> 
 1 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Consols a/c                     90 3/8  @      — 1/2 
 2 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Consols cash                    90 3/16 ,,     — 5/16
 3 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Egyptian 4 % Unified            104 ¾   ,,     105 ¼ 
 4 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Egyptian 4 ½ % State Domain     104 --  ,,     105 – 
 5 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Egyptian 3 ½ % Government Pref. 101 --  ,,     102 — 
 6 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Egyptian 3 ½ % Inscribed        98 --   ,,     100 --
 7 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Egyptian 4% Daira l980          100 ½   ,,     101 ½ 
 8 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Turkish Unified                 87 3/4  ,,     88 —  
 9 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    Austrian Gold 4 %               99 --   ,,     101 --
10 LONDON STOCK EXCHANGE. ""    French 3% Rentes                97 ½    ,,     98 ½

Original answer :
Here's a possible approach with html_table from rvest package and tidyverse transformations. Note : your XML, as displayed, isn't valid.
### Packages
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

### Parse the XML and transform the result as character
a=read_xml("C:/Users/YourName/Downloads/YourFile.xml")
b=as.character(a)

### Replace the content of the XML to conform the tables to HTML tables structure
b=str_replace_all(b,"cell cols","td colspan")
b=str_replace_all(b,"row","tr")
b=str_replace_all(b,"cell","td")

### Parse the result of the transformation
c=read_xml(b)

### Get all ids of the tables
attr=html_elements(c,xpath = "//table") %>% html_attrs() %>% unlist()

### Get all the tables
temp=c%>%
  html_elements(xpath = "//table") %>%
  html_table()

### Declare a function to transform the tables
### Transform the last column from character to numeric
transform=function(x,y){x %>% slice(-1) %>% mutate(id=y,
                                  label=x[1,1][[1]],.before=1,
                                  X2=as.numeric(X2))}

### Apply the function
done=map2(.x = temp,.y = attr,.f = transform)

### Stack the tables and rename the columns
end=bind_rows(done) %>% rename_with(.fn = ~str_replace(.x,"X","cell."),
                                    .cols = starts_with("X"))

Output :
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  id    label    cell.1        cell.2
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>
1 a     Stuff    Thing              1
2 a     Stuff    Another thing      2
3 b     Nonsense Thing              3
4 b     Nonsense Anything           2
5 b     Nonsense Another thing      2


Thanks, this approach works perfectly on the XML sample I supplied. But as you note, it's not valid XML. When I try your approach on a real document, I am having trouble selecting particular nodes and maintaining readable xml after substitution (at the ### Parse the result of the transformation c=read_xml(b) step). I added a line to my question describing my real world problem.

OK. I've provided another method to output the tables. Since dataframes have different number of columns, there are not stacked together but stored inside a list as a result (but you can do it if you want). Code is roughly commented (warning : variable naming is awful).

Avoid use of XML package as it is not actively maintained. In fact, there is a proposed 2024 Google Summer of Code R project to Supporting Migration from XML Package to xml2.

Thanks for the input. Yes, we could replace XML functions with new ones of xml2. Fun fact, despite the fact not being "actively maintened" XML still manage to get 3 updates in 2023 when xml2 got 2. "The best broths are cooked in the oldest pans", isn't  it ?:)

Consider XSLT, the special purpose language designed to transform XML files. Specifically, you can run a transformation to flatten the nested XML by moving ancestor::* nodes to sibling nodes to each <cell>.
R's xslt package (extension of xml2) can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Otherwise, you can use external processors (Saxon, Xalan, xsltproc) or languages (Java, Perl, Python, PHP) to run the transformation and load final into R.
XSLT (save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/body">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::row[not(@role)]"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
     <xsl:copy>
       <id><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/@xml:id"/></id>
       <label><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/row[@role='label']/cell"/></label>
       <cell1><xsl:value-of select="cell[1]"/></cell1>
       <cell2><xsl:value-of select="cell[2]"/></cell2>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online Demo
R (transform and map new <rows> to dataframe columns)

library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# READ XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml("myInput.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("myScript.xsl", package = "xslt")

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
new_doc <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

# RETRIEVE ALL NODES
recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(new_doc, "//row")

# BIND EACH CHILD TEXT AND NAME
df_list <- lapply(recs, function(r) {
  vals <- xml2::xml_children(r)
  
  df <- setNames(
    c(xml2::xml_text(vals)), 
    c(xml2::xml_name(vals))
  ) |> rbind() |> data.frame()
})

# COMBINE ALL DFS
stuff_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
stuff_df
#   id    label         cell1 cell2
# 1  a    Stuff         Thing     1
# 2  a    Stuff Another thing     2
# 3  b Nonsense         Thing     3
# 4  b Nonsense      Anything     2
# 5  b Nonsense Another thing     2

